# Recursive function with for loop python

Tags: python, file, for-loop, recursion

I have a question that should not be too hard but it has been bugging me for a long time.
I am trying to write a function that searches in a directory that has different folders for all files that have the extension `jpg` and which size is bigger than 0.
It then should print the sum of the size of the files that are in these categories.

What I am doing right now is

```
def myFuntion(myPath, fileSize): 

    for myfile in glob.glob(myPath): 
        if os.path.isdir(myFile):
            myFunction(myFile, fileSize)

        if (fnmatch.fnmatch(myFile, '*.jpg')):
            if (os.path.getsize(myFile) >  1):
                fileSize = fileSize + os.path.getsize(myFile)


    print "totalSize: " + str(fileSize)
```

This is not giving me the right result.  It sums the sizes of the files of one directory but it does not keep summing the rest. For example if I have these paths

```
C:/trial/trial1/trial11/pic.jpg  

C:/trial/trial1/trial11/pic1.jpg  

C:/trial/trial1/trial11/pic2.jpg
```

and

```
C:/trial/trial2/trial11/pic.jpg  

C:/trial/trial2/trial11/pic1.jpg  

C:/trial/trial2/trial11/pic2.jpg
```

I will get the sum of the first three and the the size of the last 3 but I won´t get the size of the 6 together, if that makes sense.

Comment: Have you ever heard about [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)

Answer (score 1):

You are ignoring the result of the recursive call; `fileSize` is not shared between calls.

Instead of passing in `fileSize` to recursive calls, sum the returned sizes:

```
def myFunction(myPath): 
    fileSize = 0

    for myfile in glob.glob(myPath): 
        if os.path.isdir(myFile):
            fileSize += myFunction(myFile)

        if fnmatch.fnmatch(myFile, '*.jpg'):
            fileSize += os.path.getsize(myFile)


    return fileSize
```

then print the final total returned by the outermost call:

```
print myFunction('C:/trial/')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.walk) to solve this problem.

This is how I would do it -

```
import os
import sys

def get_file_size(path, extensions):
    size = 0

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if (file.lower().endswith(extensions)):
                size += os.path.getsize(os.path.join(root, file))

    return size

print(get_file_size('.', ('jpg', 'jpeg')))
```